# dataelement td for smartpaginator

Tags: jquery, html

I set the smartpaginator parameters to below. When it does paging on GUI. it is showing some empty space between the data rows and head. I don't know why this is happening. Please help.This is urgent.

```
    $('#pager_bi').smartpaginator({ 
        totalrecords: rec_count,
        recordsperpage: 150, 
        datacontainer: 'bi', 
        dataelement: 'td',
        theme: 'custom',
        initval:cur_page_bi,
        onchange: this.onPageChangeBi
    });
```

this is a screen shot:
[image]

```
    var count = ~~(response_data.length / 5);
    var rem_count = response_data.length % 5;

        rec_count = response_data.length;

        for (var j=1;j<=count;j++) {

            for(var i=5;i>0;i--){
                tbl_entry[i-1] = '<td style="width:20%;text-align:center">' + response_data[j*5-i].imsi + '</td>'
            }

            num_list += '<tr>'
                + tbl_entry[0]
                + tbl_entry[1]
                + tbl_entry[2]
                + tbl_entry[3]
                + tbl_entry[4]
            +'</tr>';

        }

    if(rem_count != 0){

        for(var j=rem_count;j<5;j++){
            response_data[count*5+j]="";
        }

        for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
            tbl_entry[i] = '<td style="width:20%;text-align:center">' + response_data[count*5+i].imsi + '</td>'
        }

            num_list += '<tr>'
                + tbl_entry[0]
                + tbl_entry[1]
                + tbl_entry[2]
                + tbl_entry[3]
                + tbl_entry[4]
            +'</tr>';

    }

    var tbl_head = '<th style="width:20%">IMSI(s)</th>';

    num_table = '<hr>'
        + '<table border="0" float="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="bi" class="results_mini">'
            + '<tr>'
                + tbl_head
                + tbl_head
                + tbl_head
                + tbl_head
                + tbl_head
            + '</tr>'
            + num_list
        + '</table><hr>'
        + '<div id="pager_bi" style="margin: auto;">';

    jQuery('#imsi_tbl').html(num_table);

    $('#pager_bi').smartpaginator({ 
        totalrecords: rec_count,
        recordsperpage: 150, 
        datacontainer: 'bi', 
        dataelement: 'td',
        theme: 'custom',
        initval:cur_page_bi,
        onchange: this.onPageChangeBi
    });
```

Comment: can you post the html for this screenshot?

Comment: I sent this to the html div element. so it is not showing anything in the html source code. any way this a normal simple table with 5 columns. when I give the dataelement as <tr>, it shows the view as we expect. but not for this case. I gave the dataelement as <td> since I want the whole record count but not row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer..I edited these areas in the jquery extension.

added a new setting as columns.
changed the dataelement back to tr from td.
as the total records multiplied the no of tr elemnts by columns and added if their is an reminder.

ex: five columns per row and there are 27 records. then the total no of records will be 5*5+2.

Problem solved.